# Frame Animation doesnt run on second click

Tags: android, handler

It work well on the first tap,
but then on the second tap it doesn't respond. It waited for 1 second then execute 'generateRandom()' method

Can anyone help please?

My code:

```
    paper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            player.setImageResource(R.drawable.papel1);
            setTimerImage4Bot();
        }
    });


    public void setTimerImage4Bot() {
      try {
          handler = new Handler();
          frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)bot.getDrawable();
          frameAnimation.setCallback(bot);
          frameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);

          frameAnimation.start();
          Log.i("BaoAnh", "START");

          handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
              public void run(){
                  frameAnimation.stop(); 
                  Log.i("BaoAnh","STOP");
                  generateRandom();
              }
          },1000);

      }catch (Exception e) {

      }
}
```

Comment: I seldom use Handler, have you try timer.schedule?

Comment: Implements a new TimerTask like new TimerTask(){@Override public void run(){ // do your stuff here }}

Comment: @JeffLee do you have any example please? :(...i would love to try but i dunno how to...>"<...im have not done anything to do with thread, handler, timer before :(...

Comment: sure, I post the full below :D

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class AnimationTask and implements the interface TimerTask

```
private class AnimationTask implements TimerTask{
  @Override
  public void run(){
    // Run you code here
  }
}
```

Inside your onClick method:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.schedule(new AnimationTask(), 1000);
```

Hope that I can help you :D